# How to verify findElement in Div?

Tags: selenium-webdriver

I can't capture with findElement the class, xpath etc. in:

1. https://economia.estadao.com.br/noticias/geral,por-que-nao-tres-em-uma,70002648617
2. click on: entre aqui para ler a matéria.

I already tried several ways.

My code is

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.setProperty("webdriver.gecko.driver","C:\\ESTADAO\\Browsers\\geckodriver.exe"); 
    WebDriver navegador = new FirefoxDriver();  
    navegador.get("economia.estadao.com.br/noticias/…); 
    navegador.manage().window().maximize(); 
    navegador.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(20, TimeUnit.SECONDS); 
    navegador.findElement(By.xpath("/html/body/div/div/div[2]/div[1]/div[2]/div/a/div[2]")).click(); 
}
```

[image]

Comment: What ways? What happened? Give an actual example.

Comment: Hi Jon, Please,   I need to access  the site https://economia.estadao.com.br/noticias/geral,por-que-nao-tres-em-uma,70002648617  and to click on: "entre aqui para ler a matéria".

Comment: Yes, I understood that from the question. It's unclear what *problem* you've had in trying to implement that.

Answer (score 0):

Try this Xpath

```
//b[contains(text(),'entre aqui para ler a matéria ')]
```

This will work.

Answer (score -1):

Since the text is within the `a` tag, the following will work:

`findElement(By.cssSelector("a[href*='login']")).click()`

Comment: Hi Friends,
  I'm trying but without success. For now I thank you very much. 
If someone wants to access the site and try to capture I'm happy.
But I'll try the solutions you sent.

Comment: Hi Friends


I've tried every possible command, I've honestly never seen anything like it. I have even used advanced commands from the site https://saucelabs.com/resources/articles/selenium-tips-css-selectors and I did not succeed. If anyone can, I'll pay for lunch, but for me, that's enough !! The path to this is: https://economia.estadao.com.br/noticias/geral-por-que-nao-tres-em-uma.70002648617 and click on: entre aqui para ler a matéria 
Very grateful to all who tried to help me !.

Answer (score -2):

Most modern browsers support developer mode. Use "inspector" to copy xpath of the element you are interested in. For your example:

```
/html/body/div/div/div[2]/div[1]/div[2]/div/a/div[1]/b
```

Comment: This kind of xpath locator use is bad practice, and why xpath has a reputation of being terrible in the test automation community.  Using an absolute xpath of this length has a high probability of breaking with any HTML change.

Comment: Right, but still valid and easy way to get started.